# Unity 5.4 - Zooming RTS camera without FoV manipulation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a RTS-esque camera control system for my game and I've hit a wall and am unsure how to proceed.

What I want to happen is the following:

1. Mouse Click + Drag = Move the camera around the world (works)
2. Mouse Scroll Wheel Click + Drag = Rotate camera around the world (works)
3. Mouse Scroll Wheel = Zoom in/out using MoveToward/Transform.Forward..etc (sorta works)

In another script I have FoV zoom working, but it is not ideal for the type of experience I want to create.  Instead I am trying to physically move the camera in the direction it is pointed.

This current script is 90% functional in that it can *do* all the things listed above, but when I click + drag to move to a new location after scrolling to zoom, the camera resets to the original position.

Here is what happens in Update():

```
    void Update ()
{
    currentPosition = transform.position;
    scrollAxis = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;  
        isPanning = true;
    }
    // cancel on button release
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
    {
        isPanning = false;
    }
    //move camera on X & Y
    else if (isPanning) 
    {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition - mouseOrigin);
        Vector3 move = new Vector3 (pos.x * -panSpeed, pos.y * -panSpeed, 0);
        Camera.main.transform.Translate (move, Space.Self);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0 );
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3( transform.position.x, transform.position.y - (transform.position.y - (initialPosition.y)), transform.position.z );
    }
    //rotate camera with mousewheel click
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(2)) {
        yRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -80, 80);
        xRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation = xRotation % 360;
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(yRotation + initialRotation.x, xRotation + initialRotation.y, 0);
    }
    //zoom with scroll
    if ( Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0 && !isPanning) {             
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10000f * scrollAxis, Space.Self ); 
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3( transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z );
    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of a friend.

Needed to reset the initialPosition Vector3 each time I zoomed, to prevent from snapping back to the original location.

```
if ( Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0) {             
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10000f * scrollAxis, Space.Self );
initialPosition = transform.position;
}
```